# Get products which are back in stock in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How to get products which are back in stock i.e whose quantity is changed from 0 in Magento recently?

Answer (score 0):

Open Admin > go to catalog> Manage Product > Select multiple product that have 0 qty > Select UPdate attribute (left to submit button) > Submit > Product Information > Inventory > Change Qty > save.

Comment: Hi Abhinav, what I mean to ask is if product goes out of stock and they are made back in stock i.e their quantity is increased, I want to display such products in frontend, how can I do this?